# Aggregate data from array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have the following schema:

```
{  "_id": {
    "$oid": "58c0204d9f10810115f13e5d"
    },"OrgName": "A",
     "modules": [
    {
        "name": "test",
        "fullName": "john smith",

        "_id": {
            "$oid": "58c0204d9f10810115f13e5e"
        },
        "TimeSavedPlanning": 520,
        "TimeSavedWorking": 1000,
        "costSaved": 0
    },
    {
        "name": "test1",
        "fullName": "john smith",

        "_id": {
            "$oid": "58c020f85437c22215be92cc"
        },
        "TimeSavedPlanning": 0,
        "TimeSavedWorking": 1000,
        "costSaved": 500
    }
]
}
```

I want to aggregate the data within the **"modules"** array for all documents where `OrgName = A` and outputs the following totals.

```
TimeSavedPlanning = 520 (because 520 + 0 = 520)
TimeSavedWorking = 2000 (because 1000 + 1000 = 2000)
costSaved = 500 (because 0 + 500)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just supply each field for the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) accumulators. And use the "double barreled" [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) to "sum" both from arrays, and from documents:

```
Model.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "OrgName": "A" } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "TimeSavedPlanning": { "$sum": { "$sum":"$modules.TimeSavedPlanning" } },
    "TimeSavedWorking": { "$sum": { "$sum": "$modules.TimeSavedWorking" } },
    "costSaved": { "$sum": { "$sum": { "$modules.costSaved" } }
  }}
])
```

You have been allowed to use [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) like that since MongoDB 3.2. Since that release it has "two" functions:

1. Takes an "array" of values and "sums" them together.
2. Acts and an "accumulator" within [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to "sum" values provided from documents.

So here you use "both" functions by "reducing" the arrays down to numeric values per document, and then "accumulating" via the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/).

Of course the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) does the "selection" right at the beginning of the operation chain. Since that determines the selection of data, and you put that there for that purpose, as well as the fact you can use an "index" from that "first" stage.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I will test it now and respond accordingly. Just one question though, I have doing some research and came across `$unwind`. Certain sources suggest using `$unwind` to unwind that array. Do you think that is okay?

Comment: @Skywalker Oh God no!! `$unwind` should be avoided unless you absolutely need to use it. The only time it really should be used in modern releases is where the "values" from the array need to form part of the "grouping key" itself. Modern versions are pretty well equipped with operators that obviate any need to use `$unwind` in most common cases. Use as a "last resort" only.

Comment: Again Thanks. Sorry for asking so many questions. Could you explain what you meant by " the "values" from the array need to form part of the "grouping key" itself". I just wanna make sure I understand perfectly. Again Thanks!

Comment: @Skywalker If you have "another question" about using `$unwind` then [Ask a new Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). I'm answering the question you actually asked above. Which is how you get your sums. This is how you do it "in the most efficient manner possible".